# Why cherry-pick is causing conflicts

Tags: git

I'm trying to recover from massive merge/rebase havoc. In a nutshell I have a feature branch **F** that has some changes that must be merged into master **M**. But it's impossible with rebase/merge because whole **F** is broken (some people merged to it, others rebased it breaking Golden Rule of Rebase). So in order to merge somehow work made on **F** into **M** I decided to do cherry-picking only commits with actual work to completely new branch **FEATURE-FIXED**. So I did:

```
git pull -- on master to be sure it's updated
git checkout -b FEATURE_FIXED
git cherry-pick hash-of-commit-from-FEATURE
```

And now I have conflicts with every cherry pick I do.  I thought that I'll simply take the content from cherry-picked commit and apply it **FEATURE-FIXED** without to much work - simply override files. But apparently not. Probably I don't fully understand how cherry-pick works. Why I get conflicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `git cherry-pick` is just a shortcut to do a rebase of a single commit. So if the commit you are picking is causing conflicts, you'd need to resolve these just as if you were doing a (one-commit) rebase.

EDIT: It seems `git cherry-pick` can be used for more than one commit. I did not use/see this before, and it seems this feature is not related to the question.

Comment: Hmmm, still don't get it. So rebasing single commit with cherry-pick is different from the situation if I would simply copy/paste the file from this commit manually and did a new commit ?

Comment: It depends. If in your copy-paste action you just overwrite whatever is in the way without looking at it, then this is exactly the difference you mentioned. If, while copy-pasting, you think about what you are changing, this is the same process as if you were doing a rebase. In other words, git is careful and only applies the commit (patch) if the existing code fits to the old state mentioned in the commit. A commit is not just the new state (added/modified lines), but also information about where it should be applied, and what the previous state looks like at that position in the code.

Comment: It's really more the other way around, that `git rebase` is built from `git cherry-pick` (plus some branch manipulation).

Comment: That may be true. I hope the term "shortcut" is not confusing, as cherry-picking is shorter/faster/easier to type than going through the process of rebasing a single commit.